# How can I put a Transac SQL block into a function that I can reuse in Stored Procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have code to take the [Correct] column of a table with a particular QuestionId and make it it to a character string:

Here's the code that was suggested to me. It really just has one input which is the [QuestionUId] and one output which is a string looking like "001110" or "00111" or "111" etc.

```
-- I need to actually search by QuestionUId so I have this to get the QuestionId
DECLARE @QuestionId int;
SELECT @QuestionId = QuestionID
FROM dbo.question 
Where QuestionUId = '87e6bbac-651f-4fdb-862b-412979f71847';

;WITH Partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionId ORDER BY AnswerId ASC) AS RowNumber
    , COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionId) AS ColumnCount
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), Correct) AS Correct
  FROM
    @Answers
  WHERE
    [QuestionId] = @QuestionId
),
Concatenated AS (
  SELECT RowNumber, ColumnCount, Correct FROM Partitioned WHERE RowNumber = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
      P.RowNumber
      , P.ColumnCount
      , C.Correct + P.Correct AS Correct
  FROM
    Partitioned P
    INNER JOIN Concatenated C
        ON P.RowNumber = C.RowNumber + 1
)
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Correct) AS Correct
FROM
    Concatenated
WHERE
    RowNumber = ColumnCount
```

The code works but I would like to make this code available so it can be used by more than one stored procedure.

Can someone tell me is there a way I can put this code into a function or should I just put it into another stored procedure and if so then how could I do that and how could I call it ?

FYI here's the tables that are used and some sample input and output data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuestionId]  INT,
    [QuestionUId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Answer] (
    [AnswerId]    INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionId]  INT              NOT NULL,
    [Correct]     BIT              NULL
);

AnswerId   QuestionId   Correct   >>>>> needed a string "001"
19         8            0
20         8            0
21         8            1

AnswerId   QuestionId   Correct   >>>>> needed a string "10"
22         9            1
23         9            0
```

Comment: you can put your code into a stored procedure and then call it every time you need,what's the problem?

Comment: @Farrokh - This code above is part of a larger stored procedure. I was not sure how to put this into a small stored procedure and call it from the larger one. Also was not sure if SQL Server had the concept of functions and if this would be more suited to be a function.

Comment: ok, you can create a procedure same as other,and to call it use "EXEC" command,EXEC [sp_name] @variables=value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your code returns a single varchar value. So you can create scalar function from it. It will look something like that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunc
(
  @QuestionId int 
)
RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RetVal varchar(20)

-- I need to actually search by QuestionUId so I have this to get the QuestionId
;WITH Partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionId ORDER BY AnswerId ASC) AS RowNumber
    , COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionId) AS ColumnCount
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), Correct) AS Correct
  FROM
    @Answers
  WHERE
    [QuestionId] = @QuestionId
),
Concatenated AS (
  SELECT RowNumber, ColumnCount, Correct FROM Partitioned WHERE RowNumber = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
      P.RowNumber
      , P.ColumnCount
      , C.Correct + P.Correct AS Correct
  FROM
    Partitioned P
    INNER JOIN Concatenated C
        ON P.RowNumber = C.RowNumber + 1
)
SELECT
    @RetVal = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Correct) AS Correct
FROM
    Concatenated
WHERE
    RowNumber = ColumnCount

RETURN @RetVal
END
```

Then you call call it from any other `T-SQL` code (queries, procedures, other functions):

```
DECLARE @QuestionId int;
SELECT @QuestionId = QuestionID
FROM dbo.question 
Where QuestionUId = '87e6bbac-651f-4fdb-862b-412979f71847';

SELECT dbo.MyFunc(@QuestionId)
```